# Update Manager issues

Tags: upgrade, wubi

I am still getting used to dual running Ubuntu on my Windows 7 machine using Wubi. I currently have Ubuntu 12.01 and want to upgrade to 13.04. According to the instructions here :http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

I first need to launch the dash and search for an "Upgrade Manager". I do that but the only option I get is a software updater.

Any help?

PS, I am still getting used to using a terminal so I would really appreciate not using the terminal quite yet till I am more familiar with it (if at all possible).

Answer (score 0):

First, open your terminal [Ctrl + Alt + T] and type this command

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

after installed, search from dash update manager and run it, now click on check button, if there update available, update it, after update you can upgrade your system for newer version

Answer (score 0):

The *Update Manager* (note, not *Upgrade Manager*) is called *Software Updater* in Ubuntu 12.10. So run that. It will tell you that there is a new release available and give you the option to upgrade to it.

Make sure you have 3 GB free space before attempting to upgrade. Consider backing up your important data first. Also consider whether it's a good idea to upgrade a Wubi install, or rather switch to a normal dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu is longer supporting wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes?action=show&redirect=RaringRingtail/TechnicalOverview#Ubuntu_downloader_for_Windows_discontinued) so I recommend you upgrade to a full install. Before you do this you should backup all of your files and important data. Then follow the installation instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it's much easier to use the terminal esecially when getting used to Unity or any new desktop environment. You also say 12.01, so i'm assuming you mean 12.10? If you mean 12.04 then you will need to do a upgrade twice.

Open Terminal:

Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get upgrade